# How to create a article from an external website (eg. WordPress)?

Tags: joomla-3.x, wordpress

I would like to create or buy a script that would be able to post a new article on Joomla from a WordPress website.  I often find the opposite as a solution...

How can code this outside of the local Joomla environment?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting the WP post to become a new article in the Joomla database or just display the WP post on the Joomla website?

Comment: I would like the wordpress article to become a new article in Joomla indeed.

However, to make is more simple, how can I post a new article in a Joomla installation from an external website?  I would figure the wordpress part on my own afterward...
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think anything like this exists, due to the massive difference in the database structure for both CMS's

Comment: OK.  So basically to post an article in Joomla each plugin is doing direct db access?  No api nothing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the API for Joomla to add articles.

Google is your friend: [Using the Joomla! 3.3 API to add articles programmatically](https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/204-using-the-joomla-api-to-add-articles-programmatically)

Comment: Dead website: do you have any alternative content? The webarchive did not catch the zip http://web.archive.org/web/20170225192736/https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla

Answer (score -1):

I think [obGrabber](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/obgrabber) is the most suitable Joomla extension with what you want.

Comment: it's the opposite side I want to send from Wordpress to Joomla.